# Rails Devise - Create user and update associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**Ruby version: 2.6.3**

**Rails version: 6.0**

I have 2 models

1) User

```
has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
accept_nested_attributes :address
```

2) Address

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

I used devise for user model. Address model has some records already but they aren't associated with the user.
When user comes for registration that time i have to show the list of available addresses which are not associated with any user.

I wanted to use a nested form for this situation. I override devise registration controller, but attributes are not correctly in parameters.

here is my code of registration form

```
  <%= f.fields_for :address do |sc| %>
    <%= sc.label :address %>
    <%= sc.select :address, options_for_select(Address.available_addresses&.map{ |i| [i.address, i.id] }), class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
```

parameters

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"MN6zE3Z7B7zhQupa6kvbqGN4kmc8pAHRrdqtKipDclki3f6H5M919YCe9O7b+M8X49wuD3UczzpRJDl0Fmx0SQ==", "user"=>{"first"=>"daa", "last"=>"dasa", "email"=>"aa@g.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "address_attributes"=>{"address"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first, :last, address_attributes: [:id, :address]] )
  end
```

the main thing is it is not passing as attributes. it is passing only as `address: [:address]`  . if i write `f.fields_for :address` it is not showing in view. but if i write `fields_for :address` than only it is showing in form.
its quite weird why it is not working as expected.

I don't have to create a new record of address. How can I associate existing record of has one to a user?

**Update**

When I use address attributes it is just creating a new record for the address instead of updating address record for the user.  it is quite strange for me why it is not updating record and inserting a new one. I just wanted to update user id of an address record. I don't want to create a new record of address model.

**Update**
I resolve my issue with below code

```
new.html.erb

  <%= fields_for :address do |sc| %>
    <%= sc.label :address %>
    <%= sc.select :address, options_for_select(Address.available_addresses&.map{ |i| [i.address, i.id] }), class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>

users/registrations_controller.rb
if resource.persisted?
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
     address = Address.find(params[:address][:address])
     address.update_column(:user_id, resource.id)
```

I really wanted to know why this is happening, I used nested attributes, but it was just creating new record rather creating new user and updating address. it is a very small issue I wanted to figure it out what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you show us your `User` controller and mainly your `permit_params` please?

Comment: @morissetcl added application controller. i used devise's registration controller. no change in that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me:

1. In `user.rb`, override the `address_attributes=` method with:

```
def address_attributes=(address_attrs)
  self.address = Address.find_or_initialize_by(id: address_attrs[:id])
  self.address.attributes = address_attrs
end
```

2. In the registration form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :address, resource.address ? resource.address : resource.build_address do |address_form| %>
    <%= address_form.label :id, "Address" %>
    <%= address_form.collection_select :id, Address.where(user_id: nil), :id, :address, include_blank: "Choose address", class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

3. Registrations Controller:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, address_attributes: [:id]])
end
```

References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864783/11883546

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48014151/11883546

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i would also like to update your code.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I just find better solution for the registration form. Can you check if this would work for you ```<%= f.fields_for :address_attributes do |address_form| %>```, so I can update my answer. Appreciate it!

Comment: Its better to keep it as it is. because `f.fields_for :address` or association is standard way. better than `address_attributes`

Comment: @mosaaleb's solution is architecturally better because it avoids building the association in the view (ie. it keeps proper MVC separation).

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate devise controllers and configure the `registrations_controller.rb` [Configure devise controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/#configuring-controllers)
 since you need to build the address after creating new user.

`rails g devise:controllers users -c=registrations`

And add the controllers to the devise_for routes:
For example:
`devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }`

Then you can edit sign_up_params to include `address_parameters`

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first, :last, address_attributes: [:your_address_attributes])
end
```

Also you need to override `new` in `registrations_controller` to include building the address

```
def new
  super { resource.build_address }
end
```

To know how this works, you need to have a look at [`registerations_controller`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

for the views part you still need the `f.fields_for :address`

Hope this helps.